# how do i update a variable on button click using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was coding the frontend for a game me and my friends are making but i want it to update the money amount when you click the beg button but when i click the beg button it says

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jasper Karlsson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\tkinter\main.py", line 14, in begg
    balancee += moneyearned
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'balancee' referenced before assignment
```

here is a part of my code

```py
balancee = 12
def begg():
    moneyearned = random.randrange(101)
    balancee += moneyearned
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Poor", message=f"You earned {moneyearned} Bobux from beggin")
```

Comment: make it global: add `global balancee` at the beginning of the function definition

Comment: Or pass ```balancee``` as a parameter

Comment: Now no errors are given but it still doesnt update the balancee variable?

Comment: You mean ```moneyearned```

Comment: @Sujay passing `balancee` as a parameter in this case accomplishes nothing, first of that variable is already accessible, second it will change the value only locally still

Comment: It is hard to tell why it doesn't update Your money variable or more like why do You think so because adding that `global` certainly changes the global value of that variable meaning that the variable's value has changed, there is sth else but You haven't shown the code for that, please provide a [mre]

Comment: I made `balancee` global and it worked, so I can't reproduce your problem.